# What kind of filter can be used to filter sterilize ADC?

Tags: microbiology

I am using [this recipe](https://phagesdb.org/media/workflow/protocols/pdfs/PHProtocol_ADC.pdf) to mix my own ADC (Albumine+Dextrose+Catalase), without the catalase for a microbiology application.

It says use a filtering apparatus to sterilize the ADC because it can not be autoclaved. We tried using a vacuum filtering apparatus with both 0.22 um and 0.45 um PEF filters, but they clogged immediately.

We have successfully used the same filters to filter other reagents in our lab.

What kind of filtering apparatus/material would be able to filter sterilize this recipe for ADC?